# Mapping enterprise roles in ADF Security to groups in Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, weblogic, oracle-adf

I am trying out implementing ADF Security with AD Server and Weblogic server.
I have deployed adf application to my weblogic and at the same time configured AD Server on weblogic as well. I can see all the users and the group in the weblogic console from the AD server and also the enterprise group that was created as part of ADF security. My question is how do the group of AD server and the enterprise role of ADF get mapped in weblogic?

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every enterprise role will be automatically mirrored into an application role at runtime. Therefore, if you use the same names for both, there is no need of explicit mapping.

Otherwise - if your enterprise roles have a different semantic and granularity than your application roles - you will need to either create the mappings from Jdeveloper, or do it from Enterprise Manager at runtime, or programatically using OPSS API.

Comment: I tried keeping the name of my enterprise role the same as my active directory group but am.still getting authentication failed. I didn't add any users to my enterprise roles.. As per my understanding users need to come from the ad server. Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: If your authentication is failing, this means you are not even reaching the roles phase. Loading the roles happens only if authentication is succesfull.

Comment: Do you have any link for this, have been breaking my head over this for some time.

Comment: I did not add any users to my enterprise roles in jazn-data.xml, just the application roles which is mapped to enterprise role. This has the same name as the group in the active directory. But still its not authenticating.

Comment: Your problem  probably comes from the way you configured Active Directory Provider in weblogic. First, make sure you are getting AD users listed in Administration Console.

Comment: I am getting all the users displayed in the admin console of WLS. Should I add users to the enterprise roles in jazn.. I have not, as per what I understood users are maintained in the ad server

Comment: Forget about application/enterprise roles, you are not reaching that point yet. Even with wrong roles, you should be able to authenticate. Do you have all your Authentication Providers set as SUFFICIENT? How about password, do you check PLAIN TEXT option or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76957/discussion-between-zdroid-and-florin-marcus).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved I created an enterprise role on the ADF security side with the same name as that of the Active directory group mapped to WLS. Also I made sure that the users displayed from the said group had their login-names displayed in the WLS console rather that the display name.

I was under the notion that the WLS would fetch the user credentials from the active directory but what was actually happening was authentication was happening against the names in the WLS listing so my authentication was failing.

Resolved this by getting the login-names to the WLS.

Thanks Marcus for the suggestions.